# Is there a Perl module to replace Argparse module in Python programming?

Tags: python, perl

To remove a language dependency, I need to use any module or code to handle command line argument in Perl. Earlier I was using the Python **Argparse** module to handle the command line arguments.

My Python code with argparse module:

```
import argparse

default_database_config='config/database.config'
default_general_config = 'config/general.config'
commandLineArgumentParser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
commandLineArgumentParser.add_argument("-dconfig", "--dconfigaration", help="Database Configuration file name", default=default_database_config)
commandLineArgumentParser.add_argument("-gconfig", "--gconfigaration", help="General Configuration file name", default=default_general_config)
commandLineArguments = commandLineArgumentParser.parse_args()

database_config_file = commandLineArguments.dconfigaration
general_config_file = commandLineArguments.gconfigaration
```

How do I convert the above Python code to Perl code?

Comment: Have you started on it yet? The usual suspect for command line options in Perl is https://metacpan.org/pod/Getopt::Long.

Comment: I first tried to use Getopt::ArgParse but failed to install the module and now I started working one Getopt::Long . Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: That should go in the question, along with why it failed. The way your question is now, it will likely get closed as off-topic.

Comment: Thanks for your comments about the question and I changed the question title little bit.

Answer (score 6):

Here's a basic example using [Getopt::Long](https://metacpan.org/pod/Getopt::Long), pretty much Perl's de-facto standard for argument parsing:

```
use Getopt::Long;

my $ip;
my $port;
my $foreground = 0; # defaults to 0 if not sent in
my $stdout = 1;     # defaults to 1 if not sent in
my $debug;

GetOptions(
    "ip=s"       => \$ip,         # string
    "port=i"     => \$port,       # int
    "fg"         => \$foreground, # bool, flag doesn't need a param
    "stdout"     => \$stdout,
    "debug=s"    => \$debug,
);
```

Call like this:

```
script.pl --port 7800 --ip 127.0.0.1
```

Or:

```
script.pl -p 7800 -i 127.0.0.1
```